# Tax implications of currency exchange between friends?

Tags: taxes, currency, foreign-exchange, gift-tax, friends

I am a US and French citizen and have bank accounts in both countries. One of my friends is a Permanent Resident in the US and also has French citizenship, with bank accounts in both countries.

I have a need for US Dollars, whereas he has a need for Euros. If I transfer EUR 20,000 from my French account to his French account, and he transfers the spot price equivalent (let's say USD 25,000) from his US account to my US account, are there any tax implications for him or for me, as we're simply exchanging the equivalent value in different currency (no profit)?

Are there any specific forms or agreements that we would need to fill-in or execute to document this transaction?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no tax implications for converting currency. If you use currency conversions as part of investment, then there would be, but in your scenario there are none.

Comment: This presumes the transaction takes place at a reasonable exchange rate, of course.  If either party makes a real profit on the deal, that profit is taxable income.

Comment: @keshlam the op was quite clear on that point.

Comment: True.  Sorry, at  a volunteer event and short on sleep.

Comment: Thanks ADV. The nuance is that there is no "conversion"  via a currency converter, money exchange desk or a bank. I want to make sure it is not viewed as being a "gift" from him to me in the US, and a "gift" from me to him in France. Does the fact that the value exchanged is equivalent (at the spot price) cancel out the gift aspect such that this is considered a currency conversion? Thanks again

Comment: @Beefie why are you worried about gift? Gift is when you give something without getting anything in return. Don't overthink it.

Comment: @ ADV. It's really more to reassure my friend. He'll use the Eur eventually but I'm the one really asking for the favor (and the USD). All the friends I asked were less than thrilled to consider the exchange given potential tax or reporting impacts. Given that I'm requesting the service / convenience, I figured I'd do some digging beforehand. Appreciate the answer and the follow-up.

Comment: @Beefie if you want to reassure and sleep better - just keep the bank receipts for both the transfers. If anyone asks - you can show that it was an exchange at the spot rate and nothing more.

Comment: Does the US citizen have to prepare to include proof of this being a fair currency exchange in their IRS tax return? Or would you say that for $25K you don't need to offer "excuses" and so you keep proof just-in-case?

Comment: @ilya if anyone asks that would be FinCEN, not the IRS.

Comment: So since you're not making revenue, you're not expected to report anything to the IRS, nor report anything preemptively to any other U.S. government institution?